# Capybara Choose radio button not working

Tags: html, rspec, capybara

I've done this maybe 100 times but for the life of me I can't understand why it's telling me it can't find this object. Here is my html:

PS I've verified that I'm on the correct page and I can see the advisor when I do a `save_and_open_screenshot`

#### HTML

```
<div class="panel">
  <%= form.label :advisor, class: "panel__label" %>
  <%= form.radio_button :advisor_or_client, "advisor", class: "panel__input__radio advisor" %>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <%= form.label :client, class: "panel__label" %>
  <%= form.radio_button :advisor_or_client, "advisor", class: "panel__input__radio client" %>
</div>
```

#### TEST

```
choose('advisor')
```

#### ERROR

```
Failure/Error: choose('advisor')

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find radio button "advisor"
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Based on the info provided how can I select the radio button for my feature spec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`choose` locates the radio button by name, id or label text - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#choose-instance_method .  Rather than that you are specifying the `value` of the input (I'm assuming the second value should be "client" rather than the "advisor" you have).  Since you don't have ids, and name would be ambiguous, you can use the `option` parameter (matches value) to narrow down to the correct radio. Therefore

```
choose('trade_request_submission[advisor_or_client]', option: 'advisor')
```

or potentially

```
choose(option: 'advisor')  # if you don't have any other radios with that value
```

Another option is to specify the label text but that would require adding the ids to the `input` elements that match the `for` attributes on the labels to link them correctly, in which case you could do

```
choose('Advisor')
```